# How to get all the web page elements as tree using selenium web driver in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Say i am trying to use the selenium web driver to get the page source. I just want to know how to get all the html elements in a tree like structure.

```
Iwebdriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

I need to get all the html elements like the below way.

```
[-] Html
 [+] Head
 [+] Body
```

etc

Can some only provide me some idea how to achieve this irrespective of the page.

Thanks,
Lokesh